# How to parse json file containing list inside a section in python?

Tags: python, json

I have a smaple.json as follows:

```
{"Detail":[
    {
    "DocType":"txt",
    "Name":"hello.txt",
    }
    ]}
```

I need to have the value aginst the "Name" Field. i tried in my script as follows:

```
file="c:/sample.json"
for list in file:
    if (str(list['Detail'])=='None'):
         print("Do nothing")
     else:
         ana = list['Detail']
         val =  (str(ana)[1:-1])
         print val
         print val['Name']
```

and i get output as :

```
  {"DocType":"txt","Name":"hello.txt"} 
  error:print (ana['Name'])
  TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

So what am i doing wrong how shall i get the "Name" field details.

Comment: you are handling a json object as a string which is not a good practice. Try to handle it as a dict and then access the elements you want. It will seem easy too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the `json` library:

```
import json

json_path = "c:\\sample.json"
with open(json_path) as json_file:
    json_dict = json.load(json_file)

name = json_dict['Detail'][0]['Name']
```

Answer (score 0):

error is at this line `print val['Name']`. Because `val` is `str` type so you can't lookup on key basis.

You should do

```
ana[0]['Name']
>>> 'hello.txt'
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`json`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) library.

```
import json

with open('sample.json', 'r') as f:
    content = json.load(f)

name = content['Detail'][0]['Name']
```

Answer (score 0):

Please see the below link on json library [https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html]

1. open the json file
2. use json.loads() to decodethe data.
3. access it with headers

/code

```
>>> import json
>>> with open('test.json','r') as e:
...     data = json.loads(e.read())
... 
>>> data
{u'Detail': [{u'DocType': u'txt', u'Name': u'hello.txt'}]}
>>> data['Detail'][0]['Name']
u'hello.txt'
>>>
```